How to vertically center the content section of a PrimeVue Panel?
I am using the PrimeVue Panel element and tailwind.
I want the content area to be vertically centered. I do not want the header to change, only the content area.
I have tried putting flex items-center justify-center on the inner div but it doesn't vertically center.
<Panel header="Keep This Heading Here">
  <div class="flex items-center justify-center">Make this vertically centered</div>
</Panel>

I have also tried adding it to the content class as a pass through but it still doesn't vertically center.
<Panel header="Keep This Heading" pt:content:class="flex items-center justify-center">
  <div>Make this vertically centered</div>
</Panel>

Here is a live minimal reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/bqzl55-dakehh?file=src%2FApp.vue
How can I make this work?

In your example, the panel has display: flex; flex-direction: column; So you can center the content using margin: auto 0;. In Tailwind, this is the my-auto class:
<template>
  <Panel
    header="Header"
    class="flex h-[300px] flex-col"
    pt:contentContainer:class="my-auto"
  >
    <div>
      Please vertically center this text within the Panel with 300px height. The
      header should not be centered or changed.
    </div>
  </Panel>
</template>


Instead of setting height to the panel, you can set the height to the content div you want to center. I think you can't center that panel without overriding some primeVue CSS classes, because the parent of your count doesn't have height 100%.
Here an example:
<template>
  <Panel header="Header">
    <div class="h-[300px] flex items-center">
      Please vertically center this text within the Panel with 300px height. The
      header should not be centered or changed.
    </div>
  </Panel>
</template>

Another solution is to use position: absolute;, but I don't prefer this way.
Here the example:
<template>
  <Panel header="Header" class="h-[300px] relative">
    <div
      class="absolute top-[50%] transform translate-y-[-50%] bottom-0"
    >
      Please vertically center this text within the Panel with 300px height. The
      header should not be centered or changed.
    </div>
  </Panel>
</template>


In order to achieve vertical centering of content, you need to add styles to the content container. According to their documentation, you can customize the style of the content container by modifying the p-panel-content-container and p-panel-content classes. You can easily achieve this by creating a CSS file, but if you insist on using Tailwind, here's how you can do it:
<template>
  <Panel header="Header" class="flex h-[300px] flex-col [&_.p-panel-content-container]:flex [&_.p-panel-content-container]:grow [&_.p-panel-content-container]:items-center">
    <div>Please vertically center this text within the Panel with 300px height. The header should not be centered or changed.</div>
  </Panel>
</template>


Update
If you prefer pass through:
<template>
  <Panel
    header="Header"
    class="flex h-[300px] flex-col"
    pt:contentContainer:class="flex grow items-center"
  >
    <div>
      Please vertically center this text within the Panel with 300px height. The
      header should not be centered or changed.
    </div>
  </Panel>
</template>

